# [Help]PHP to PDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, html2pdf

I have one invoice layout from my company that I transformed into a php file that have many css, my php file generate the invoice using mysql connections to fill some spaces, now I need to transform this html to pdf format. I tried to use tcpdf, but the images and css isnt good, since have many different tables. Does it have a simple tool to convert this generated html output from php, into pdf format ? 
Thanks

Comment: tcpdf and other libraries are the "simple" way of doing the conversion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wkhtmltopdf.
example after you have download it,etc:

```
wkhtmltopdf http://link.com file_name.pdf
```

Comment: Oh god, it worked like charming *o*
I did via command line, is it possible to do this command in php?

Comment: The font that pdf generated is slightly a bit different from the original one (Trebuchet MS) is it possible to fix this ?

Comment: You just need to use:                                                   --header-font-name * <name>       Set header font name (default Arial)

Comment: I tried to do the command
>wkhtmltopdf --header-font-name Verdana http://localhost/nsfe/i
ndex.php test.pdf
Tried to change Verdana to Trebuteched MS, Arial, Calibri, but the result is always the same s:
Btw thank you so much for your help